# 2 task pane open when clicking on 2 buttons from ribbon in office 365 word add in

Tags: office365, office-js, word-web-addins

I have 2 buttons on the ribbon in Office 365 word addin.

```
...
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">                        
   <TaskpaneId>button1</TaskpaneId>
   <SourceLocation resid="myURL" /> // ~remoteURL/pages/text.html?seacrhtype=1
</Action>
...

..
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">                        
   <TaskpaneId>button2</TaskpaneId>
   <SourceLocation resid="MyURL.Url" /> //// ~remoteURL/pages/text.html?seacrhtype=2
</Action>
..
```

I open the same html page and pass query param based on which ribbon's button click.

The issue which I am facing is that when I click on a button1, it opens a task pane.

If I click on button2, it opens another task pane without hiding/closing the first task pane which already opened so I have 2 task pane on the same word page.

Is there any way so at a time, only one task will be open? If I click on a different button then only that related taskpane will open and work.

How can I hide the first task pane when I click on the second button and vice versa?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [closeContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=excel-js-preview#closeContainer__) method closes the UI container where the JavaScript is executing. The behavior of this method is specified by the following:

- Called from a UI-less command button: No effect. Any dialog opened by displayDialogAsync will remain open.
- Called from a task pane: The task pane will close. Any dialog opened by displayDialogAsync will also close. If the task pane supports pinning and was pinned by the user, it will be un-pinned.
- Called from a module extension: No effect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where can I use this closeContainer? It could not help me.

Comment: There is no other way to close a task pane programmatically from web add-ins.

Comment: If I have multiple buttons in the ribbon and all button's clicks open different URL in task pane, I may have multiple task pane at same time. Is it correct?